# MySQL compare leading zeros comparison

Tags: mysql

I have database table where account no are 001 and 01 but i want to update only 01 record not 001 .
query update account_name where account_no = 01.
but it update both records in database but i want only one.

Comment: What is type of account number column?

Answer (score 3):

Using a number type for the account number will not work then, since the number of leading zeros is arbitrary.

Consider using a string type: under such a scheme the leading zeros will be significant.

(If in fact the field type for the account number is already a string-like type, then use `account_no = '01'` for the query).

Comment: i cant change the database ,my requirement is just to update table with comparison of field like 001 or 01.field is vharchar